# how do I connect a BN59-01006A samsung rc to an Arduino Uno IR receiver module

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wireless, infrared, library

I have this remote control (BN59-01006A):

[image]

and this IR receiver brick(Keyes IR receiver):

[image]

I managed to connect the IR brick to my Arduino Uno. I downloaded [this library](https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote) and used a basic Arduino code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {

    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to capture some HEX. values and display them through the serial monitor. The IR module works (the internal LED blinks every time I use the remote control towards it), but it's not displaying anything. What Am I missing? Do remote controls have to be calibrated to connect to a standard IR module?

Thank you much for your help.

Comment: Which pin did you connect it to? (and: What Arduino board do you own). Hasn't there been a change in pin numbering? Can you see any pin toggeling on the line?

Comment: @TomL. the board I'm using is an Arduino Uno, the pin is 11. I am not sure what you mean by "pin toggling on the line". Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how it is done on the Arduino but you should be able to read the value of the pin in your infinite loop. For a first test, simply read the value und output it via the serial port. you should see that it is sometimes 0 and sometimes one as long as you press a button on the remote control. If you have a scope, you can also use that to detect a level change of the pin when you press the button. Can you add some dummy serial output at the beginning of your sketch to see if it does something at all?

Comment: thanks for your help, I managed to solve the problem. upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your device on the break out it is likely a GP1UX311QS that is can run either 3.3V. Go with connecting the - to GND and the + to 5V.

That device will likely receive 38kHz modulated signals. It is possible (likey) your remote is 38kHz modulated. It is possible it may be something else. Where the blinking LED on the breakout is a good indicator that it is demodulating something.

Ken's Library has an example called "IRrecvDump.ino". Start with this. Where on the keyes breakout the S pin is the demodulated signal and on Ken's library's are defaultly connected to pin 11. Where the + and - are power and ground.

The "IRrecvDump.ino" will attempt to decode a variety of typical formats of data. Where Samsung is not in the initial list. But it will dump the timing of the data stream. So that you or others can determine the pattern. And possibly add it to fork of the github.

Where you can review all the inidividual forks and ADDs on the GitHub [Network Diagram](https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote/network)

A quick Google of: samsung shirriff github. Shows several forks that indicate they have added Samsung.

1. https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote/pull/3
2. https://github.com/targettio/Arduino-IR-remote/blob/master/IRremote.h
3. etc..

Comment: Thank you much for your complete answer. I had a circuit issue I was able to debug based on the IR dump example. Upvoted and solved!